# redux error handling for fetchs

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm working on error handling w/ fetch's in redux. Do people typically write reducers/actions error handlers for every single request like the videos from redux.js.org? I was thinking about dispatching the same action w/ an error flag to handle errors, but I don't know if that's the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, yes. I ordinarily have actions like `GET_THINGS`, `GET_THINGS_SUCCESS`, and `GET_THINGS_ERROR`, and then have a case statement in the reducer to handle each action. Most React devs I know do it the same well. In general, I would suggest following that pattern. That said, it does result in you having to handle a lot of `GET` actions and `ERROR` actions basically the same way, since you'll likely just be adding something like `{ Loading: true }` or `{ Error: true }` to the state...

Answer (score 0):

For error handling and posting / putting data  I use a generic way of raising a dialog for the user to indicate success or failure.

e.g. have a NoificationsAction 
const NotificationAction = (open = false, message = '', status = 'success') => ({type: NOTIFICATION, payload: {open, message, status}})

and some dilaog component which raises a dialog or snackBar to display a message

Dispatch this when your request fails

```
myRequest()
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.status === 200) {

                dispatch(projectsSuccess(response.data))

            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {

            dispatch(NotificationAction(true, `My Error Text : ${error}`, 'error'))

        })
```

This way you reduce your boiler plate code in reducers